# How to sub split when reading from text file

Tags: java, arrays

Rather a little bit confused

I have a text file that is formatted like this

FooBoo,male,20,10/04/1988

I know how to  split a string for example

```
public loadData() {  

   String filepath = "G:\\Documents\\MEMove\\XXClients\\data.txt";

    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));

    String line = bufReader.readLine();

    while (line != null) {

        // String[] parts = line.split("/");
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        String part1 = parts[0];
        String part2 = parts[1];

        int part3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
        String [] sDOB = line.split("/");
        int sDOB1 = Integer.parseInt(sDOB[4]);
        People nPeople = new People(part1,part2,part3,sDOB1);

       readPeopleList.add(nPeople);
        line = bufReader.readLine(); 
    } //end of while 
    bufReader.close();

    for(People per: readPeopleList)
    {
        System.out.println("Reading.." + per.getFullName());

    }
}// end of method
```

the problem is how do I split DOB /  its not working for I am getting NumberFormatException Error

any ideas

thanks

Comment: can you put some sample data form data.txt

Comment: Try debugging line by line - looks like `line.split("/")` should be `parts[3].split("/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, split line using delimiter `","`:

```
String line = "FooBoo,male,20,10/04/1988";
String[] parts = line.split(",");
```

Then, split last part using delimiter `"\"`:

```
String dob = parts[parts.length - 1];
String[] sDob = dob.split("/");
for (String s : sDob) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Edit: You can convert `sDob` into an `ArrayList` as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> sDobList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sDob));
```

Comment: it appears to work, thanks for the help the only thing is when I want to add the sDob values in the ArrayList  I am getting error String can't be an array which of course it can not.

Comment: If you want to convert the array into an ArrayList, see the edit. If not, please clarify what you want to do.